Valuation of forward-starting call with non-zero strike
We know prices for call spread options with strike $K\neq0$ that is an option whose payoff $\varphi(S_T^1,S_T^2)$ is given by:
$$\varphi(S_T^1,S_T^2):=(S_T^1-S_T^2-K)^+$$
where $S^1,S^2$ are the prices of two distinct assets, do not admit a closed-form expression when the assets have a log-normal distribution.
Does the same hold for forward-starting calls on price returns? Namely letting $S$ be the price of some asset and $\Delta>0$, the option with payoff:
$$\varphi(S_T,S_{T+\Delta}):=(S_{T+\Delta}-S_T-K)^+$$
Ultimately both $(S_T^1,S_T^2)$ and $(S_T,S_{T+\Delta})$ are two pairs of log-normal variables with some correlation structure, but I was wondering whether in the second case, the different evaluation times might allow for a close-form solution.

Using slightly different notation, your spread option (SO) price is
$$
SO = E_t \left[ E_T [(S_T' - S_T - K)_+] \right] = E_0 [ C(S_T, S_T + K)]
$$
Under Black-Scholes I think you can just integrate this using the lognormal distribution for $S_T$. Generalizing to local volatility it will still be a numerical integration, with density obtained from market prices via Breeden-Litzenberger.

So to answer your question: no I don't think there is a closed-form solution, at best a numerical integration.
